# How to Filter and Restore Specific SQL Database Backups Using dbatools in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, restore, dbatools

I'm working with a directory of mixed SQL Server backup files and need to restore a specific database using dbatools in PowerShell. Below is the directory structure of my backup folder:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator> tree \\dc1\backup /F
Folder PATH listing
\\DC1\BACKUP.
│   Hadr_endpoint_cert.cer
│   Hadr_endpoint_cert.pvk
│
└───NODE1
    └───MSSQLSERVER
        ├───AdventureWorks2016
        │   ├───Full
        │   │       Full_AdventureWorks2016_20240219011641.bak
        │   │
        │   └───Log
        │           Log_AdventureWorks2016_20240219011647.trn
        │
        └───Credit
            ├───Full
            │       Full_Credit_20240219012730.bak
            │
            └───Log
                    Log_Credit_20240219012735.trn

PS C:\Users\administrator>
```

When attempting to restore the Credit database onto `node2` with the following command, I encounter issues:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path \\dc1\backup -Recurse -Include *.trn,*.bak
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance node2 -Path $files -DatabaseName Credit -NoRecovery -ExecuteAs sa
```

This results in the error:

```
WARNING: [01:27:36][Restore-DbaDatabase] Multiple Databases' backups passed in, but only 1 name to restore them under. Stopping as cannot work out how to proceed.
```

Using this command instead:

```
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance node2 -Path \\dc1\backup -DirectoryRecurse -DatabaseName Credit
```

Leads to a different error:

```
WARNING: [01:32:00][Get-DbaBackupInformation] Failure on node2 | The media family on device '\\dc1\backup\Hadr_endpoint_cert.cer' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family. RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
```

I understand that I can manually select files that are related to the Credit database by their naming convention, but what if the backup files do not have the database name in their filename? What would be the best approach to automate this restoration while filtering out unrelated files?

Any guidance or tips on the proper use of dbatools for this scenario would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're searching in the root of your backup folder, dbatools doesn't really have a way to know which .bak files it should take. So in your first example it makes perfect sense it will try to restore multiple databases.

Comment: Why don't you just do `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path \\dc1\backup\NODE1\MSSQLSERVER\Credit -Recurse -Include *.trn,*.bak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew the actual path you can just go directly to the folder for that database.

Otheriwse, you can use [`Get-DbaBackupInformation`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Get-DbaBackupInformation) to get only relevant backups for that database.

```
$backups = Get-DbaBackupInformation `
  -Path "\\dc1\backup"
  -DatabaseName Credit `
  -SqlInstance node2 `
  -DirectoryRecurse;

"Backups found:";

$backups;

$backups |
Restore-DbaDatabase `
  -SqlInstance node2 `
  -DatabaseName Credit `
  -NoRecovery `
  -ExecuteAs sa;
```

Comment: Hi Charlie, in this case, will the `Restore-DbaDatabase` function parse the backup file headers again?

Comment: I'm not sure. I would imagine it would just pass all the paths to the server to work out